# Build a string with variables, cutting null variables off

Tags: c#, string, variables

I want to write a string with some variables but when the specific value isn't necessary, it can be cut off.

e.g.:

```
int apples = 5;
int oranges = 8
int bananas = 0;

string.Format("I got {0} apples, {1} oranges, {2} bananas.", apples, oranges, bananas)
```

> Output: I got 5 apples, 8 oranges, 0 bananas.

I want to cut off ", 0 bananas", as they aren't necessary to show here.
My only solution would be if-states for every fruit... Imagine I can have 10 fruits...

```
if (bananas == 0)
{
    string.Format("I got {0} apples, {1} oranges.", apples, oranges)
}
```

My next problem is that I can have more than one fruit to be 0. This will be an endless if-state within an if-state...
Is there any solution to solve this within one line?

I don't even know what I can do here. I just know the ways of inverting variables with the use of `+` operator, using `string.Format()` or using `$` before the actual string.

Many thanks!
Netroshin

Comment: with tuple (name, count) you can go with: [`$"I got {string.Join(", ", new List<(string name, int count)>() { ("apples", 5), ("oranges", 8), ("bananas", 0) }.Where(i => i.count > 0).Select(i => $"{i.count} {i.name}"))}."`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQ9uRl)

Comment: _Is there any solution to solve this within one line?_ Why do you need one line? Did you skip over the lessons about code readability and maintainability?

Comment: ...and what if all fruits are zero?...

Comment: @user09938 the fruits are just the example to show you what I wanted to. To be precise: I want to show someone his stats in my bot for Twitch, some stats can be null and don't need to be shown, like prestige. the whole string can be "You are a SHINY Pokemon which needs 345exp to levelup, with a PRESTIGE of 2" (the capslocked words aren't necessary when you aren't a shiny or don't have a prestige level yet)

Comment: @Idle_Mind the string contains some information to make sense (I just had the fruits as an example to explain it better) but you can say, if nothing is there you can say "I got nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have a bunch of different `if` statements for every possibly combination, you can just build the string with a single `if` for each fruit. This can be simplified using the `?:` ternary operator, which has a condition on the left side of the `?`, followed by a result if the condition is true, then a `:` followed by a result if the condition is false. Since we want a comma at the end of each string, I added a `TrimEnd(',')` to remove the last one:

```
string result = "I got" +
    ((apples > 0 ? $" {apples} apples," : "") +
    (oranges > 0 ? $" {oranges} oranges," : "") +
    (bananas > 0 ? $" {bananas} bananas" : "")).TrimEnd(',');
```

---

You also might consider putting your data into a better structure. Instead of storing them as `int` types, you could create your own type that has both a `string` name and an `int` quantity. In this way, you can filter a list of these items on the quantity (remove all where `quantity == 0`), and then print them out using the `Name` property.

For example:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    // Create a list of fruits
    List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
    fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "Apples", Quantity = 5 });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "Oranges", Quantity = 8 });
    fruits.Add(new Fruit { Name = "Bananas", Quantity = 0 });

    string result = "I got " + string.Join(", ", fruits
        .Where(fruit => fruit.Quantity > 0)
        .Select(fruit => $"{fruit.Quantity} {fruit.Name}"));

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is very helpful and the exact thing I needed. many thanks!

Comment: `"@" + ChatName + " You are a " +
((Trainer[1] == "No" ? "" : "shiny ") +
PokeName + " Level " + ActualLevel + ", you have " + ExperiencePoints + "EXP and " +
(ActualLevel < 100 ? "need " + ExperiencePointsToNextLevel + "EXP for the next level!" :
"therefore " + ExperiencePointsOverflow + "EXP more than you need! You can use Prestige!")`
25 LoC before, now 4 LoC. very nice!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 StringBuilder sb;
  sb.Append("I got ");
 if(oranges > 0){
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} oranges,"));
 }
 if(apples > 0){
    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} apples,"));
 }
 ...
 var res = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: If you don't have any `bananas` (but you still have some apples and/or oranges) you will end the sentence with an unwanted comma (`,`). For example `I got 2 apples, .`

Comment: Yup, I left resolving the end punctuation to op

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp_StackoverflowAnswering1
{
    class Fruit
    {
        public String Name;
        public int Value;

        public Fruit(String name, int value)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Fruit> myFruits = new List<Fruit> { new Fruit("Banana", 0),
                                                     new Fruit("Apple", 5), 
                                                     new Fruit("Orange", 10) };
            String output = $"I got {String.Join(", ", myFruits.Where(fruit => fruit.Value > 0).Select(fruit => $"{fruit.Name}={fruit.Value}"))}.";
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```